# Regex to keep only portion of a URL

Tags: regex, grafana

I have a set of data looking like that:

```
/v2/ports/PF-12345
/v2/services/cloud/PF-12345
/v2/services/cloud/connections/PF-12345
/v2/services/cloud-routers/PF-L3-CUST-12345/connections
/v2/services/cloud-routers/PF-L3-CUST-12345678/connections/PF-L3-CON-12345678/bgp/c03664c5-fd8d-8623-acb5-bda4b545fb32
/v2.1/services/cloud-routers/PF-L3-CUST-12345/connections/PF-L3-CON-12345/status
```

I am trying to modify this data set like below (basically removing the version and the IDs/UUID in the URL).

```
ports
services/cloud
services/cloud/connections
services/cloud-routers/connections
services/cloud-routers/connections/bgp
services/cloud-routers/connections/status
```

I have been trying to figure out the right regular expression but can't get something working.

Here is a [regular expression I worked on](https://regex101.com/r/1diinq/1).

```
\/.*(?=\/.*?)
```

This is to use in Grafana to transform data just FYI.

Comment: Kindly add your tried code in form of regex in your question, else you may get downvotes and close votes, its highly encouraged on Stack Overflow that questioners should add their efforts in their question, thank you.

Comment: got it, I added a link on regex101 with what I have been trying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your shown samples only, please try following regex.

```
^\/[^\/]*\/(.*?)PF-[^\/]*\/(.*?)(?:PF-[^\/]*\/(?!PF-[^\/]*\/)(.*))?$
```

Here is the [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/r1WpJJ/1) for shown regex.

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above regex.

```
^\/[^\/]*\/       ##From starting of value matching / till next occurrence of / including / here.
(.*?)             ##Creating 1st capturing group where using lazy match(till next condition, explained below).
PF-[^\/]*\/       ##matching PF- till next occurrence of / including / here.
(.*?)             ##Creating 2nd capturing group where using lazy match(till next condition, explained below).
(?:               ##Creating a non-capturing group here.
  PF-[^\/]*\/     ##Matching PF- till next occurrence of / including / here.
  (?!PF-[^\/]*\/) ##Using negative look ahead to make sure its not preceded by PF- till next occurrence of / including / here.
  (.*)            ##Creating capturing group with greedy match here.
)?$               ##Closing non-capturing group and keeping it optional at the end of value here.
```